# Open Facebook url in Safari instead of native app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook

is there any way to open Facebook url (ex. http://www.facebook.com/facebook) in Safari instead of native app? I'm tried to do this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.facebook.com/facebook"];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
```

but iOS automatically launch native client (of course if it's installed) if you try to open url with in facebook domain. thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ok, I think I found answer, you must replace "www.facebook.com" with "facebook.com" in url.

Something like this:

```
NSString *facebookUrlString = @"http://www.facebook.com/facebook";

if ([[facebookUrlString pathComponents] count] > 0) {
    if ([[facebookUrlString pathComponents][1] isEqualToString:@"www.facebook.com"]) {
        NSMutableArray *pathComponents = [[facebookUrlString pathComponents] mutableCopy];
        [pathComponents replaceObjectAtIndex:1 withObject:@"facebook.com"];
        facebookUrlString = [NSString pathWithComponents:pathComponents];
    }
}
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:facebookUrlString]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy link to the messenger app and send to yourself. Open the link on messenger app and click on share and will apear open with facebook app