# Facebook page link open in facebook app instead of safari browser

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

I am developing an iPhone app in that i need to open facebook page link in safari browser. I did it by following code on button clicked method.

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.facebook.com/facebook"]];
```

This code will open safari browser in iPhone and display facebook page. But problem is when in device facebook application is installed then this code open facebook app instead of safari browser. Problem created when in device have facebook app installed. I want same behaviour whether there is facebook application is installed or not.

Suggest some idea. Code is fully welcome. thanks in adv.

Comment: `I want same behaviour whether there is facebook application is installed or not` Why? There's a reason for this behavior, FB (believes) app provides a better experience on mobile. Also, possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351818/open-facebook-url-in-safari-instead-of-native-app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

make it this way

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"fb://profile/<page id>"]]){
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"fb://profile/<page id>"]];
}else{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString: @"http://www.facebook.com/<page name>"]];
}
```

Comment: This will open FB app, I believe OP *doesn't* want to open FB app.

Comment: this code will check if facebook app is there in device then your url will open in facebook app and if your device do not have facebook app installed then it will open url in normal safari browser. It is always batter to check if app is there or not and user like to open every request related to facebook in facebook native app not in safari browser.

Comment: That's exactly what's happening at present. Pl read the q again.

Comment: i could not found anything if your device have facebook app installed and still it's open any facebook page request in safari browser. According to my understing code must open any facebook request in facebook native app only. If your device don't have facebook installed then you are free to open in safari browser.