# How to make url that open in Safari for iOS Facebook Messenger app instead of in-app web browser

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, safari

[iOS] I'd like to make facebook messenger bot that sends a URL. Once the URL is tapped, I want it to open the URL in native safari.app instead of an in-app browser in Messenger.app. I tried Safari-search URL scheme, but it doesn't work. Is there any way to open native safari by modifying URL without modifying iOS native source code because, you know, I can't make any change for FB messenger native app?

Typical scenario:

1. I am managing bot and send FB message with amazon product URL, let's say, [https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B00T85PMWY/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00T85PMWY).
2. The receiver tap the url.
3. Safari will open and show the page.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

[Open Facebook url in Safari instead of native app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15351818/open-facebook-url-in-safari-instead-of-native-app?rq=1)     go get your answer

Comment: I added `:80` at the end of url, but it didn't work. Could you clarify?